# How to plot arbitrary math functions using Python and matplotlib?

Tags: python, math, plot

I want to plot any mathematical function such as y=x**2 or y=sin(x)/x (anything basically).
The problem is, I can only plot functions defined in numpy such as `np.sin`, `np.cos` or `np.tan`.
The entire point here is how to avoid "hard coding" vectors and then plot those.

How can I plot arbitrary functions? Here is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Let a be starting point on x
#Let b be end point on x
#Let f be the function you wish to plot

CornflowerBlue="6495ed"

def plotf(a,b,f):
    
    x=np.linspace(a,b,num=b*10)
    y=np.array([])
    
    for i in range (len(x)):
       
        y = np.append(y,f(x[i]))
        
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.plot(x,y,color="CornflowerBlue")
    plt.axhline(y=0,color="black")
    return
```

Comment: `I can only plot functions defined in numpy such as np.sin, np.cos or np.tan`. What do you mean by that? If i use `plotf(-5, 5, lambda x: x**2 + 1)` and then `plt.show()` it correctly renders a function that is not defined in numpy.

Comment: Thank you! The trick was to use lambda

Comment: `def f(x): return x**2 + 1` with `plt.show()` and `plotf(-5, 5, f)` works the same, I still don't get what your question is.

Comment: just a tip: if you're using numpy arrays, you don't need to loop through them. In other words, `y = x**2 + 1` is all you need to do

Answer (score 1):

You could try `sympy` as it should allow you to play with a variety of mathematical functions without explicitly hardcoding them:

```py
from sympy import *

def plotf(a,b,f):
    plot(f, xlim = (a,b)) 

plotf(-10, 10, "sin(x)/x") # or plotf(0, 2, "x**2"), or (almost) whatever
```

See for details https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html!